# calling a reactjs web application from a .net web application

Tags: .net, reactjs

So, we have a huge predeveloped .Net web portal, and another small project developed in ReactJs. I want to call my react project from the .Net page.

Is it possible?

Please note that both the portals are hosted on same server and I need to pass some parameters from the .Net page to ReactJs landing page. I dont know anything about .Net, I am a React developer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to share date between React.js and .Net or do you need to add React.js to your .Net application ?

Comment: What do you mean by you want to call the react js application from .net ? Do you want to serve react using .net? Or do you want to send data from .net to react ?

Comment: @Muljayan I have two separate projects. one in .Net and other in ReactJs.I want to call reactJs project from .Net project and I also need to pass some date from .Net page to React Page.

Comment: @MebinJoe I want to call ReactJs project from .Net and also pass some parameters from .Net to React

Comment: When you say "I want to call reactJs project from .Net project" do you mean that you want the react js application to show when you access a certain end point of the .net application ?

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee Hope this gives some idea https://jonhilton.net/use-react-in-your-existing-asp-net-app/

Comment: @Muljayan yes...

Comment: @MebinJoe I don't want to merge both the projects.

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee you can use your react.js scripts in .net app or you need to expose APIs

Comment: Yes it is possible to serve react js with .net framework . As for sending data to the react js app you will have to make api endpoints in your .net backend and  use http requests to access the data.

Comment: if, i am writing `Response.Redirect("10.51.228.59:8080/Default.jsx);` in my .Net page, its not getting redirected.its giving me error, invalid redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very straight forward solution. Posting it here if anyone else stumble upon same problem in future.

In my `page.aspx.cs` , inside the button click function, I simple wrote

```
Response.Redirect("https://myurlstring?myquerystring=myqueryvalue")
```

Now in my reactjs landing page:

```
import queryString from 'query-string'

...

componentDidMount() {
    const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
    console.log(values.myquerystring) // "myqueryvalue"
}
```